# Get dask.distributed profiling time information?

Tags: distributed, dask

I am using dask.distributed to schedule many jobs across workers. The documentation shows how to get profiling information from the Bokeh interface
[here](http://distributed.readthedocs.io/en/latest/diagnosing-performance.html?highlight=profile).

It also shows that one can obtain the raw profile information calling `client.profile()`.
However, when I call this method, the profiling information doesn't seem to include the average run time of a process, whereas it is present in the Boken interface. Is there a way to retrieve this in raw form?

Also, profile.py explains the structure of the profile information here:

```
We represent this tree as a nested dictionary with the following form:

{
 'identifier': 'root',
 'description': 'A long description of the line of code being run.',
 'count': 10  # the number of times we have seen this line
 'children': {  # callers of this line. Recursive dicts
     'ident-b': {'description': ...
               'identifier': 'ident-a',
               'count': ...
               'children': {...}},
     'ident-b': {'description': ...
               'identifier': 'ident-b',
               'count': ...
               'children': {...}}}
}
```

There is no mention of timing information here. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You should compare the value of `'count'` against the `profile-interval` value in your config.yaml file.  The `profile-interval` value is in milliseconds and determines the frequency at which we sample the working thread.  So if profile-interval was 10 and you saw 50 counts of a particular line then that line was likely active for around 500ms * threads.